# Question about interpreting interaction terms in regressions, continuous regressors

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients

lets say I am regressing a dependent variable, such as income, on years of education , height (just as an example I pikced another continuous variable), and the interacting of height on income:

$income_i$ = $\beta_o$ + $\beta_1$$height_i$ + $\beta_2$yearsedu$_i$ + $\beta_3$height x yearsedu$_i$ + error$_i$.

I know if there were binary random variables, this would be a difference in difference. but with continuous random variables, what exactly is the interpretation of $\beta_3$? It seems I can take:
$dy/dheight$ = $\beta_1$ + $\beta_3 yearsedu_i$,

which has an easy interpretation, but I can do the same but instead differentiate with respect to yearsedu and get a seemingly different interpretation:

$dy/dyearsedu$ = $\beta_2$ + $\beta_3 height_i$.

and how would this be different than the following nested model:
$income_i$ = $\beta_o$ + $\beta_2$yearsedu$_i$ + $\beta_3$height x yearsedu$_i$ + error$_i$.?